# Agregar un array dentro de otro dinámicamente

Tags: array, ios, swift

¿Cómo puedo agregar un array dentro de otro y en éste, a su vez, ir agregando más arrays en cadena dinámicamente, según me lo vaya pidiendo el código?

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres alcanzar? No queda claro con tu pregunta...
Un array de arrays? este array interno que tipo de dato contendrá (String, Int, otro objeto...)?
Quizá lo que quieres es añadir los contenidos de un segundo array a un primero?
Por qué no pones un poco de (pseudo)código con lo que te gustaría hacer, y un también el resultado que esperas?
Creo que sería más fácil ayudarte de ese modo...

Comment: Tengo que agregar a un array otro array y dento de este otro array y asi .. hasta n arrays. Los arrys que voy añadiendo no serán fijos. Estos arrays se añaden dinámicamente a medida que un usuario va creando caminos por una especie de menus y submenús y subsubmenus...En C creo que esto se podria hacer con un puntero y reservando memoria con alloc dinámicamente. A donde apunta el puntero a su vez puede contener otro elemento que sea otro puntero ... etc..

Comment: Pero entonces puede tener dimensiones indefinidas o solo 2? Es decir, 2 niveles anidados o muchos más? Entiendo que tendrás un array con muchos arrays dentro, pero no un array que dentro tiene otro array que a su vez tiene otro array dentro, y así sucesivamente... cierto?

Comment: Puede tener n niveles de profundidad. Si exacto indefinidos, como si fuera menú, submenú, submenú del submenú, etc... El array contiene objetos es decir puede ser NSString, NSInteger,...en Objective-c seria id y en Swit Any

Comment: Es decir... tu array sería una matriz de dos dimensiones no? por ejemplo [[“0-0”, “0-1”], [“1-0”, “1-1”, “1-2”]...] pero no sería algo como: [[“0-0”, “0-1”], [[1-0-0], [1-0-1], [1-0-2]], [2-0, 2-1]] verdad? No se si lo estoy liando, pero es q la complejidad es totalmente diferente!!

Comment: Ok, ignora mi último comentario que te adelantaste.. jeje! Voy a ver si doy con algo... y te respondo

Comment: Ok, se que es lioso gracias por responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a tu comentario de menú, submenú, etc... Yo te diría que ir construyéndolo en base a un array de arrays puede ser un poco complicado.

Si ese array te viene definido en un json, y lo que quieres es leerlo, sí que podrías ir recorriéndolo recursivamente.

En cualquier caso, si lo que quieres es ir guardando una estructura que se va a ir generando dinámicamente (se me ocurre que por acciones del usuario...), entonces te recomendaría tener una especie de estructura recursiva, algo como:

```
struct MenuItem {
    var title: String
    var subItems: [MenuItem]?
    var action: (()->())?
}
```

De esta manera, si lo que quieres es añadir un nuevo item de menú, podrías simplemente añadirlo al array de `subItems`:

```
var generalMenu: MenuItem = ...
var copyItem = MenuItem(title: "Copiar", subItems: nil, action: {
   // some action that this menu needs to perform
})
var pasteItem = MenuItem(title: "Pegar", subItems: nil, action: {
   // some action that this menu needs to perform
})
var editMenu = MenuItem(title: "Editar", subItems: [copyItem, pasteItem], action: nil)

generalMenu.subItems?.append(editMenu)
```

y por ejemplo para recorrerlo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
func recursivelyLoopMenuItems(menuItem: MenuItem, depthLevel: Int) {
    let levelPrefix: String = (0..<depthLevel).map({ _ in "-" }).joined()
    print ("\(levelPrefix)\(menuItem.title)")
    menuItem.subItems?.forEach({ recursivelyLoopMenuItems(menuItem: $0, depthLevel: depthLevel + 1) })
}

recursivelyLoopMenuItems(menuItem: generalMenu, depthLevel: 0)
```

lo que imprimiría:

```
Menú
-Editar
--Copiar
--Pegar
```

No sé si esto te puede servir, al menos como orientación...

Comment: Me sirve bastante creo que es lo que busco. Te explico que inicialmente es un formulario con menú de 'n' opciones de estas elijo 3 por ejemplo (a , j y e), Una vez elegidas paso a otro formulario que me mostrara las 'n' opciones a elegir de 'a' y elijo por ejemplo (alfa, beta y gamma) una vez elegidas paso a otro formulario que me mostrara las 'n' opciones de alfa y elijo por ejemplo H y B. Una vez elegidas se da el caso que ya no hay mas opciones ( Pero podría ser que hubiera otro nivel o niveles mas según que opción y seguir bajando niveles ).

Comment: Llegados aquí tengo que volver hacia atrás para que me muestre el siguiente formulario que toca mostrar que seria el formulario 'beta' con sus 'n' opciones donde se repite el proceso hasta.. un punto que ya no avanza mas y vuelve atrás a mostrar el formulario de 'gamma'  y se repite el proceso... hasta que vuelve atrás hasta el formulario de 'j' y asi.. sucesivamente hasta que se han mostrado todos los formularios.

Comment: Me suena a una especie de formulario tipo las encuestas de google forms...quizá con una estructura similar a la propuesta en mi respuesta, puedes añadir un bool (computed property) a cada `menuItem`, que calcule si todos sus `subitems` han sido visitados o rellenados, algo similar, para devolver el control al padre... si tienes que navegar entre formularios, pues usa el patrón delegado para que al volver al formulario anterior, éste sepa cuál es el siguiente formulario a visitar, o si tiene q pasarle el control a su padre, para que siga con el proceso... no se si me explico

Comment: En cualquier caso creo que una estructura recursiva como la q planteo es probablemente lo que necesitas. Tendrás que adaptarlo a tu caso particular y ver cómo lo puedes hacer funcionar

Comment: Hay me he perdido en lo de usar el patrón delegado para volver al formulario anterior. Inicialmente pensé en implementar esto apoyándome en una pila tipo LIFO guardando el formulario donde estoy actualmente y saltando al que toca según que opción para luego recuperar los formularios anteriores de la Pila.

Comment: Bueno... lo de la pila no suena mal tampoco, sería otra forma. Lo del delegate sería un ViewController con un array de`MenuItem`, con los que presentas las preguntas o opciones del formulario. Avanzas al siguiente y este avamza al siguiente, o cuando ha terminado de procesar todos sus menuItems, hace un dismiss y por medio del delegate le comunica al viewController anterior que ya ha terminado, para que así éste pueda pasar su siguiente menuItem o si ya ha acabado con todos pasarle el control a su padre. De esta forma, para el viewController saber si tiene que avanzar hacia abajo...

Comment: Mirará a ver si tiene más menuItems sin resolver. Y para saber si ya ha terminado por completo o si tiene q pasar el control a su padre, mirará si tiene asignado un delegate (si es nil su propiedad delegate)... y si está a Nil es que es el controlador raíz, con lo cual se da el formulario por completado. En realidad estarías siempre instanciando el mismo ViewController, que contendría un array de opciones (con subopciones), y un delegate para notificar al padre que ya ha acabado, o si no tiene padre, pasar al ViewController q iría al completar todo el formulario...

Comment: Puedes jugar con las transiciones para realmente no hacer dismiss visible del controlador que termina con un subformulario, sino que haces un push del nuevo ViewController, y después eliminas ese subformulario de la pila del navigationController de manera transparente al usuario... y así das siempre una sensación de estar avanzando siempre hacia delante en lugar de adelante-atrás-adelante...

Comment: Creo que ya entiendo, para mostrar los formularios lo estaba haciendo instanciando viewController una vez en el mainviewcontroller ( el principal ) y para el siguiente formulario volvia a llamar al método viewdidappear del mismo viewController con una variable que contenia el id de formulario a mostrar. Pensare en lo que comentas. No uso navigationController lo intente y el código se me complicaba porque tenia que dar saltos entre  pantallas. Uso únicamente el mismo viewController para mostrar los diferentes tipos de pantalla (quitando o añadiendo objetos para mostrar otro tipo de pantalla)

Answer (score 2):

No me queda del todo claro la forma en la que operara la funcion, por lo que entiendo todo eso se trata de insertar un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo, estas son posibles soluciones:

```
private func add_items_to_array()
{
    var arreglo_principal = [[String : Any]]()
    var segundo_arreglo = [[String: Any]]()
    var tercer_arreglo = [String: Any]()

    segundo_arreglo.append(["tercer_arreglo": tercer_arreglo])
    arreglo_principal.append(["segundo_arreglo" : segundo_arreglo])
}

private func add_items_to_array2()
{
    var arreglo_principal = [Any]()
    var segundo_arreglo = [Any]()
    var tercer_arreglo = [Any]()

    segundo_arreglo.append(tercer_arreglo)
    arreglo_principal.append(segundo_arreglo)
}
```

En la primera funcion puedes guardar arreglos y luego llamarlos mediante claves y en la segunda puedes agregar el elemento que sea a cada arreglo.

Comment: Seria con n niveles de profundidad no solo para 3

Comment: Si explicaras la forma en la que deberia funcionar este proceso entonces podria brindar un poco mas de ayuda.

Comment: Se que es complicado de explicar seria como crear un árbol apartir de ciertas opciones iniciales. Por ejemplo parto de 10 opciones fijas, de esas elijo 3 opciones, la primera opción elijada tiene x opciones mas y de esas elijo 2 por ejemplo y asi sucesivamente hasta x niveles. Cuando acabo voy recursivamente hacia atrás para elegir mas opciones que quedaban en los nodos de arriba. Cuando acabo con este nivel voy a la 2 opción de las 3 primeras que se elijieron y asi sucesivamente se repite hasta completar la 3 opción de las 3 primeras que se elijieron...

Comment: Te agradezco tu ayuda, gracias